# Extracting blocks of txt file and saving them to separate files

Tags: python, shell, editor

I have a huge `.txt` file (approx 200MB).

The structure of the file is the following

```
#l = 1
0 0 -1234 1234
0 1 -1234 1234
0 2 -1234 1234
...
n n -1234 1234

#l = 2
0 0 -1234 1234
0 1 -1234 1234
..
n n -1234 1234
...

#l = 100
0 0 -1234 1234
0 1 -1234 1234
..
n n -1234 1234
```

where `1234` stands for some generic random number, `n` can be `499` and the number of `l` blocks can be 100 as in the example.

The important thing is that I have blocks to isolate, i.e. I need to create one `.txt` file for each block starting with `#l= ...`

I want to ask if there is some intelligent way of doing this. Cutting the file manually is not at all easy, my editor has problems dealing with the size of the file. I am happy with using any solution: `shell`, `python`...

Comment: You can use `awk` to do this easily.  Have you tried?

Comment: never used `awk` before. Will have a look. Do you know the command for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this python script

```
import re

    cwf = open("0.txt","w+")
    for line in open('filename.csv'):
        if re.match(r"#l", line):
            num = re.search(r"#l\s=\s(.*)", line).group(1)
            cwf = open(num+"txt","w+")

        cwf.write(line)
```